# Visual Studio 2022 Tab Code completion not working

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

My problem is that my tab key isn't accepted as auto complete for code or inserting tabstops, instead it changes the selection of the window i am in like in any other Windows program.

I know there are similar questions on this platform but they don't match my problem.

I am using Visual Studio 2022, not Visual Code.

Ctrl + M is not a valid shortcut and can not be applied to fix this issue because there is further input needed after pressing Ctrl + M.

Thank you for your help.

Edit:

I know its unsatisfying but restarting my pc the next day worked. I have 0 clue why though. I am sorry.

Comment: This has happened to me two days in a row now. It's so frustrating. It's getting into some mode where it's using tab to navigate between UI elements instead of interacting with the editor. I assume I am fat-fingering something to initiate that state but I have no idea what's causing it. Visual Studio 17.7.3.

Answer (score 2):

This was happening to me and I figured out that hitting `Alt` by itself initiates the mode where you can use the keyboard to navigate between menus/UI elements. Hitting `Alt` again exits that mode and goes back to normal `Tab` behavior.

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution could be adjusting the IntelliCode settings by switching to the right arrow instead of using Tab for completion. Please try the following steps:

1. Navigate to Options.
2. Go to IntelliCode.
3. Select Advanced.
4. Ensure that the "Apply whole line completions on right arrow" option is
   checked.